# WatchKit 2.0 Send Message From Phone To Watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I'm wanting to be able to update my Apple Watch views if a user has both the Apple Watch app open and the iPhone app open as well. I know there is a [WatchKit 1 question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523253/ios-watchkit-how-to-send-message-data-from-iphone-app-to-watchkit-app), but I want to know if I could do this using WatchConnectivity.

Within my iOS app, I send a message:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
    // Set the session to default session singleton
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    // Fire the message to watch
    NSLog("send message")

    session.sendMessage(["action": "messageAction"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        // Display alert
        NSLog(error.description)
    })
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7007 "WatchConnectivity session on paired device is not reachable." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=WatchConnectivity session on paired device is not reachable.}
```

To send messages from the iPhone to Apple Watch, is `WatchConnectivity` `sendMessage` the correct method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only the "correct" method *if* you are looking to interactively communicate with a reachable device.

But you haven't shown where you set your session delegate or activated the session:

```
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
session.delegate = self
session.activateSession()
```

You may also want to add some checks to ensure that a watch is paired (`session.paired`), that the watch app is installed (`session.watchAppInstalled`), and that the watch is actually reachable (`session.reachable`) before trying to interactively communicate with it, to make your app more robust.

[See this guide for more details.](https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchconnectivity-say-hello-to-wcsession/)

You could also choose to fall back on a non-interactive (background) method to queue messages for your app until it is open and can receive them.